# How to remove specific elements from a nested JSON payload (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I want to create a function that will check a nested JSON for specific elements and if found, delete all instances of the element even if found in an array.

For example, let's say I have a JSON:

```
{
    "userId": "John991",
    "group1": {
        "color": "red",
        "height": "100",
        "userid": "John992"
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "userid": "John993",
            "Key3": "Value3"
        },
        {
            "group2": [{
                "userid": "John994"
            }]
        }
    ],
    "Key1": "Value1",
    "Key2": "Value2"
}
```

I want my result to be

```
{
    "group1": {
        "color": "red",
        "height": "100"
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "Key3": "Value3"
        },
        {
            "group2": [
                {}
            ]
        }
    ],
    "Key1": "Value1",
    "Key2": "Value2"
}
```

The best I've been able to do is parse the JSON, and remove the element if it exists. However, this does not take into account arrays or nested JSONs. The below code only removes "userid":"John991".

```
 var b1 = JSON.parse(JSON);

 if (b1.hasOwnProperty("userid")){
    delete b1["userid"];
 }
```

Comment: In short, you want to delete all properties, even the nested ones, that key equals to `userid`, is it?

Comment: @CalvinNunes Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a function which iterate through keys and delete the key in recursion. Something like this

```js
const input = {
  "userId": "John991",
  "group1": {
      "color": "red",
      "height": "100",
      "userid": "John992"
  },
  "data": [
      {
          "userid": "John993",
          "Key3": "Value3"
      },
      {
          "group2": [{
              "userid": "John994"
          }]
      }
  ],
  "Key1": "Value1",
  "Key2": "Value2"
};


function deleteKey(obj, keyToDelete) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    if (key.toLowerCase() === keyToDelete) {
      delete obj[key];
    }
    value = obj[key];
    if (value instanceof Object) {
      deleteKey(value, keyToDelete);
    }
  });
}
deleteKey(input, "userid");

console.log(JSON.stringify(input, null, 2));
```

Comment: thanks for providing this solution. This was indeed what I was looking for and implementing it was flawless. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad it helped you. Dont forget to mark it as answer for other people’s reference

Answer (score 2):

This function does what you want:

```js
const json = {
  "userId": "John991",
  "group1": {
    "color": "red",
    "userid": "John992",
    "height": "100"
  },
  "data": [{
      "userid": "John993",
      "Key3": "Value3"
    },
    {
      "group2": [{
        "userid": "John994"
      }]
    }
  ],
  "Key1": "Value1",
  "Key2": "Value2"
}

function objWithout(obj, property) {
  let json = JSON.stringify(obj);
  const regex = new RegExp(`,?"${property}":".*?",?`, "gi");
  json = json.replace(regex, '');
  json = json.replace(/""/, '","');
  return JSON.parse(json);
}

const result = objWithout(json, "userId")
console.log(result)
```

The function `objWithout` stringifies the provided object, does text replacement and returns an object parsed from the edited text. The text replacement searches for all instances of `property` regardless of where it appears in the object, so if `userId` happens to appear in an object which is a member of the provided object, it still gets replaced.

The Regex replaces all instances of the property and its value along with any leading and trailing `,`. In a second step, the `,` gets added again for cases where the property is in the middle of two other properties, e.g. `{"a":"b","userId":"user123","c":"d"}`.

The text replacement is done by a regular expression. You can read more about those here https://regexr.com/.

Additionally I added the /i/ flag, because your object has "userId" and "userid", but I think you want both gone.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This function was simple and genius, however implementing became very difficult as it uses backticks ` . The JS environment I was using did not allow backticks ` and I was not able to find a workaround. However, even though it takes more processing, @Ashish Modi 's solution worked much better in terms of implementing.